# popup outside my application for incoming call

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, broadcastreceiver, focus

I have a broadcast receiver for intercept an incoming call.
After that, I have to show a popup with some informations, I created an Activity PopupActivity and I call it in this way

```
       Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

the activity onCreate method is the follow

```
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.toast);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

and this is the manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".PopupActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

with HsetFinishOnTouchOutside(false) I prevent the dialog closing when I touch outside the popup, this is fine, but I want touch the dialer for answer the call.
So I need to keep the focus outside the popup without closing it.

Second question, I have a delay between the incoming call and the response of the broadcast receiver, how can I make it more responsive?

Comment: Are you getting your pop up activity on top of call activity.

Comment: A broadcastReceiver class starts the PopupActivity.
I see the dialer in background with my popup dialog in front of, but the dialog catch the focus and I can't answer the call